# angular 1.3 directive CSS optization

Tags: html, css, angularjs, optimization, angularjs-directive

I use angular 1.3 (so I can not use components), and I created a directive with some style in the templateURL. So each time I use this directive the CSS is loaded. So I would like to know is there is a way to **embedded** the CSS in the directive and load it just one time. I know I can write the CSS in a top level page but It is not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Look you are very new to use the CSS and JS, Better to load all css once from index.html

Comment: I want to use a directive like a web component.